# Betta fish is a dark blue, but color keeps fading and returning quickly; why?

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, betta, temperature

My Betta fish, named Sapphire, is a female veiltail and she's dark blue normally, but her color keeps fading and returning to normal in a short span of time and I don't know what to do. I already lost one to ich. Could it have to do with the water temperature? Should I change the water in her tank?

Comment: Almost impossible to says without images. Please edit your question and add some of the different color states.

Comment: can you please provide information  about the ph-amonia-nitrite-nitrate levels of your water.some types of fish can change color if the ph is changed(i know this sounds crazy but i have seen this myself).

Answer (score 3):

Most common reason for a betta changing colour is stress, but indeed can also be caused by illness.
If your fish changes colour regularly, and is otherwise healthy and acting normal, I think stress will be the reason. 
I've had a female betta in the past, and I would notice the same every time I did my tank maintenance. She would get more pale, and a dark horizontal stripe would appear. 
If my male betta was chasing her for some time, same thing happened. 
But of course the 'stress' can also be caused by a bad living environment. So it is important to try to find out what the cause is. 
It could also be a bad environment: Tank being too small, temperature, other inhabitants, water chemistry (pH, nitrite, ...), is the tank cycled, etc.?

Some more information can be found here [Why Do Bettas Change Color?](https://pets.thenest.com/bettas-change-color-4520.html)